# Why are extension attributes inaccessible in python protobuf objects?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I am attempting to read and analyze GTFS-realtime data from the NYC subway in Python.  So far, I have successfully used both `gtfs-realtime.proto` and `nyct-subway.proto` to generate the proper Python classes and parsed the protobuf data into Python objects.

My problem comes when trying to access certain fields in these objects.  For example, the header (`feed.header`) looks like this:

```
gtfs_realtime_version: "1.0"
incrementality: FULL_DATASET
timestamp: 1533111586
[nyct_feed_header] {
  nyct_subway_version: "1.0"
  trip_replacement_period {
    route_id: "A"
    replacement_period {
      end: 1533113386
 ...
```

I can access the first three attributes using dot access, but not `nyct_feed_header`.  I suspect this is because it is part of the `nyct-subway.proto` extension, while the other three are part of the original.

I have found this attribute accessible in feed.header.ListFields(), but since that returns a list of (name, attribute) pairs, it is at best awkward to access.

Why aren't attributes from extensions accessible by dot access like the rest of them? Is there a better or more elegant way to access them than by using ListFields?

Comment: what's the rationale to use protobuf to read a GTFS feed instead of e.g. Google's transitfeed package https://github.com/google/transitfeed? AFAIK GTFS is essentially a CSV file format.

Comment: You're correct about GTFS - it's usually delivered as static CSVs.  The question, though, is about GTFS-realtime - a related, but distinct standard for realtime transit information that uses protobuf.  See https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/

Answer (score 2):

Extensions are accessed via the `Extensions` property on an object (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#extension)). E.g. with GTFS and the NYCT extensions:

```
import gtfs_realtime_pb2 as gtfs
import nyct_subway_pb2 as nyct

feed = gtfs.FeedMessage()
feed.ParseFromString(...)
feed.entity[0].trip_update.trip.Extensions[nyct.nyct_trip_descriptor].direction
```